# How do i get rid of white space between navbar and background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, navbar

I want to get rid of white space between navbar and background image. There is about .5 an inch of white space between the navbar and background image. I have tried the container tag wrapped around the navbar and that had worked before i changed the "navbar header" to "navbar-header-sm" once i did that this white space appeared directly after the navbar. But, i need the "navbar-header-sm" because otherwise the navbar was oversized. I am just trying to get the background image to meet the navbar.

****** 1. Here is HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QuirkyBear</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header-sm">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src= "images/QBlogo.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <nav>
    </div>
<img src="images/QBhead.png" class="img-responsive">    
<!--javascript-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

****** 2.Here is CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: align;
    background: url (..images/QBhead.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.navbar {
    margin=bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#CCE1F4;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: #2f4f7f;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #2f4f7f;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #2f4f7f;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #2f4f7f;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
     background-color: #2f4f7f;
}
```

Comment: It should read `margin-bottom:0;`, you have `margin=bottom:0;` on the `.navbar` class. You also need a dash in `background-size` and no space after `url(...)` in the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your code in CSS which is this :

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#CCE1F4;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

I changed it by removing background-color, and it should work by what you want i hope and the whitespace is gone, your nav is on top of background now. :) You shouldn't call it whitespace I think, it is confusing. Maybe white background.

```
.navbar-custom {
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong.